# FileNotFoundError using open and Russian language/spaces

Tags: python, io, cyrillic

I am getting this error (sorry for the screenshot, exited tmux session and lost output):
[image: FileNotFound error screenshot]

I am sure that this file exists cuz I copied the path and tested it. I am thinking that this error could be caused by the Russian language or spaces inside the path, I tried finding the information about it online, but unsuccessful.

Anyone knows does this error caused by symbols or something else?

Answer (score 0):

Before the spaces put backslash `"\"` for example `"home/../my \directory/file/txt"`